# php - Change curdate format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As far as I can understand the curdate() mysql function returns a date like this:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

How can I do so it select it like this instead:

```
'YYYY/MM/DD'
```

I have this query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) from xeon_stats_clicks WHERE typ='4' AND curdate() - interval 7 day >= data ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Although my "data" row in the database is formatted like this: "YYYY/MM/DD"

Therefore, how can I change the query to select the date format like that?

Comment: I think the DATE_FORMAT() function will allow you to format a date however you like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the DATE_FORMAT() function in MySQL.
Also you can find [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/format-date-time-mysql/) useful

In your case the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(value) from xeon_stats_clicks WHERE typ='4' AND date_format(curdate(), '%Y/%m/%d') - interval 7 day >= data
```

EDIT: I posted an updated query but then realized that nothing really changes, because you asked about formatting **data** column and this column is not selected by query. But anyway you can use date_format() function when you need to select **data** column in custom format, for example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data, '%Y/%m/%d') from xeon_stats_clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(value) from xeon_stats_clicks WHERE typ='4' AND curdate() - interval 7 day >= DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y-%m-%d');
```